# Passing string into function. expected expressing before ']' token. Using C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm back again with another string problem. I've no idea what's wrong with this. I'm trying to pass a string into a function but GCC expects an expression from me. Help is appreciated. These errors are always so hard to debug!

```
if (fmenu == 1)
{      
 printf("\nEnter the file name: \n");
 scanf("%s", name);
 /* printf("filename: %s", name); */
     smenu = sndmenu();

    if (smenu !=1 && smenu !=2 )
    {
        printf("\nIncorrect option\n");
     smenu = sndmenu();     

     if (smenu == 1)
      file = fileoperations(name[]); /* Here, I cannot pass name[], expected expression */
     }    
}
```

Comment: Invalid syntax isn't really that hard to "debug". Get rid of the `[]`

Comment: The call to `scanf` is a buffer overflow waiting to happen.  [Read more about buffer overflows here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308)

Comment: Please could you give the data types for name (scanf) and how that relates to the variable smenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name[]` isn't a valid expression.

You need `fileoperations(name);`

Comment: Thankyou. I swear I tried this, swear it didn't work. Thankyou. I feel so silly. This is what happened the first time I asked a question too. I'll note to double check before I post again.

Answer (score 0):

`sndmenu` - what is that?

If this is homework I think that it is better that you stuggle for a while. Try a debugger. Try commenting out lines and replacing them with simpler lines to gain an understanding.

Comment: I've been struggling with various errors with the program for three weeks now. I'd appreciate you not be patronising and make assumptions about what I have and haven't done.